# Send ether to a payable function from nethereum

Tags: ether, contract-invocation, nethereum, payable

I have created a payable function in a smart contract and deployed it in a private blockchain network. Now I am using Nethereum to make rpc calls to the geth node on which the network is running.

But I am unable to find how to pass ether while calling a payable function from nethereum.

The geth equivalent of what I want is

```
Contract.function({from:"address, value:"amount"})
```

Comment: Try this -

Contract.function("function parameter if any", {from: "address", value: web3.toWei("value in ether")})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose my_function is a payable function why not to use?

`function.SendTransactionAsync(addressFrom, gas, valueAmount, augEvent);. }` 
in the valueAmount you specify the ethers to send.

For example :

```
 var my_functionFunction = contract.GetFunction("my_function");
            var tx = await my_functionFunction.SendTransactionAsync(addressFrom, gas, valueAmount, augEvent);
```

if you want to provide the function's parameters (e.g `my_function(param1,param2, param3)`) use :

```
  transactionHash = await my_functionFunction.SendTransactionAsync(addressFrom, gas, valueAmount, param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: My requirement is to also send parameters to the function.  So I should modify the code as var my_functionFunction = contract.GetFunction("my_function");
            var tx = await my_functionFunction.SendTransactionAsync(addressFrom, gas, valueAmount, augEvent, parameters);    Also What does the argument augEvent signify ?

Comment: check my previous answer i've edited it